# what is required to deploy a sharepoint app to 2 tenants?

Tags: sharepoint-online

in my understanding, SharePoint app once deployed in an App catalog can be used by any site in a specific SharePoint tenant ( Say Tenant A), as Client ID generated from SharePoint Tenant A is used to generate App package from Visual Studio.

Now, if i want the app package ( already generated) to be deployed in tenant B, what do i need?

Tenant A and Tenant B are both enterprise customers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the same .app file directly. You need to perform the following steps:

1. Register the app in Tenant B using AppRegNew.aspx page
2. Copy the new client id and secret that is generated and put them in web.config
3. Replace  the client id in AppManifest.xml or while packaging the app give the new client id.
4. Package the app again using new client id
5. Upload the app in Tenant B's app catalog and use it.

P.S. If your app is using any custom database, then you need to handle multi-tenant scenarios. If not, you are good to go.

Comment: That means my app with 10 customers, then 10 times visual studio to be opened/10 versions of code to be maintained/10 app packages to be created and then shared. i understand this is one of the ways and wondering that if there is a more effective way.

Comment: yes, if permissions allow you can upload it to SharePoint store or Seller Dashboard. The whole process is here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220033.aspx

Comment: There are some restrictions as to the permissions that app request, so you need to check it